# Toyota Tundra oil pressure

Tags: toyota, oil-pressure, oil-pressure-sensor, tundra

I have a new-to-me 2013 Tundra. When I first start it and when the engine is under load, the oil pressure gauge goes up pretty significantly. It doesn't go to 3/4, but maybe 5/8 or a little more.
I changed out the oil for 0W-20 since I'd read that it's pretty common to run the wrong oil, but that didn't seem to fix the issue.
Is this normal?

EDIT: adding more info. My question is basically "is this fluctuation normal?". My old truck was a Dodge Dakota, and once it had run longer than a minute or so the needle was dead on 50% pressure and stayed there pretty much no matter what. The Tundra goes up nearly to 75% on startup and idle (until it's run for a good five minutes) and it also pops to maybe 60% when I'm accelerating or on a hill. Cruising it actually drops slightly below 50% on the gauge.

Comment: What exactly are you stating the issue is? I'm not really following here. I get it there seems to be an oil pressure issue, but what *exactly* is the issue? If you have oil pressure which is above 1/2, I'd think there's no issue at all. My 2018 Silverado idles with about 25 psi of oil pressure (~1/4 of the gauge). This is considered normal, especially since the engine idles at around 475 rpm. Once I get on the gas a little bit (whether in park or under load), the oil goes up to about 50 psi (well over 1/2 the gauge).

Comment: I think the fluctuation is normal. The faster the engine is running, the faster the oil pump is turning, and the more pressure it makes. When the engine is cold, oil won't flow as well, and the pressure will be higher. I'd recommend running the oil which is recommended by the manufacture for your vehicle.